Change SignedInfo.CanonicalizationMethod to http://www.w3.org/2006/12/xml-c14n1
I am following the method advise from this link
SignedXml CanonicalizationMethod - http://www.w3.org/2006/12/xml-c14n11
After I applied the changes, the system run fine and does not have any error but I am still not able to show the intended result and still showing the default method as following

This is my code
 public void SignXmlFile(string FileName, string SignedFileName, RSA Key, string[] ElementsToSign)
    {

        // Process of getting the Key from Cert
        //string certificate = @"<PATH TO .CER>";
        //X509Certificate2 cert = new X509Certificate2(certificate);
        //RSA Key1 = cert.GetRSAPublicKey();

        // Check the arguments.
        if (FileName == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("FileName");
        if (SignedFileName == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("SignedFileName");
        if (Key == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("Key");
        if (ElementsToSign == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("ElementsToSign");

        // Create a new XML document.
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();

        // Format the document to ignore white spaces.
        doc.PreserveWhitespace = false;

        // Load the passed XML file using it's name.
        doc.Load(new XmlTextReader(FileName));

        // Create a SignedXml object.
        SignedXml signedXml = new SignedXml(doc);

        // Add the key to the SignedXml document.
        signedXml.SigningKey = Key;

        
       

        // Loop through each passed element to sign
        // and create a reference.
        foreach (string s in ElementsToSign)
        {

            XmlDsigC14NTransform c14nTransform = new XmlDsigC14NTransform();
            CryptoConfig.AddAlgorithm(typeof(XmlDsigC14N11Transform), "http://www.w3.org/2006/12/xml-c14n11");
            // Create a reference to be signed.
            Reference reference = new Reference();
            reference.Uri = "";

            // Add an enveloped transformation to the reference.
            XmlDsigEnvelopedSignatureTransform env = new XmlDsigEnvelopedSignatureTransform();
            reference.AddTransform(env);

            // Add the reference to the SignedXml object.
            signedXml.AddReference(reference);
        }

        signedXml.SignedInfo.CanonicalizationMethod = "http://www.w3.org/2006/12/xml-c14n11";

        // Add an RSAKeyValue KeyInfo (optional; helps recipient find key to validate).
        KeyInfo keyInfo = new KeyInfo();
        keyInfo.AddClause(new RSAKeyValue((RSA)Key));
        signedXml.KeyInfo = keyInfo;
       
        // Compute the signature.
        signedXml.ComputeSignature();
        signedXml.SignedInfo.CanonicalizationMethod = "http://www.w3.org/2006/12/xml-c14n11";

        // Get the XML representation of the signature and save
        // it to an XmlElement object.
        XmlElement xmlDigitalSignature = signedXml.GetXml();

        // Append the element to the XML document.
        doc.DocumentElement.AppendChild(doc.ImportNode(xmlDigitalSignature, true));

        if (doc.FirstChild is XmlDeclaration)
        {
            doc.RemoveChild(doc.FirstChild);
        }

        // Save the signed XML document to a file specified
        // using the passed string.
        XmlTextWriter xmltw = new XmlTextWriter(SignedFileName, new UTF8Encoding(false));
        doc.WriteTo(xmltw);
        xmltw.Close();
    }

How could I get the result for the following pictures below:


See URIString : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.xml.rsakeyvalue?view=net-8.0
